# gotoSimple() seems to reload to current action before redirecting

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Somehow it seems that when I use `gotoSimple` in the following setup, my data will be saved twice by `$object->save()` in `secondAction()`.

```
public function firstAction(){
    // get data

    // process postdata, if any

    if( $form->isValid( $postdata ) ) {
        $this->_helper->getHelper( 'Redirector' )->gotoSimple( 'second' );
    }

}

public function secondAction(){

    // get data

    // process postdata, if any

    if( $form->isValid( $postdata ) ) {
        if( $object->save( $postdata ) ) {
            // set flashmessage
            $this->_helper->getHelper( 'Redirector' )->gotoSimple( 'index' );
        }
    }

}
```

After hours of debugging I have come to the conclusion that somehow the *gotoSimple()* command in `secondAction()` triggers `secondAction()` before it redirects to `indexAction()`. I have made sure that it is in no way possible for `indexAction()` to redirect back to `secondAction()`.

Even more interesting: this only occurs in IE7 and in IE8. Can anyone point me in any possible direction to where this strange behavior may come from and how I can solve this?

**UPDATE**
By using the following lines of code in `secondAction()` right before the `gotoSimple()` command, I can be 100% sure of the fact that somehow the `secondAction()` is called twice when I press my submit button:

```
if( isset( $_SESSION['xyz-zyx'] ) ) {
    $this->_helper->getHelper( 'flashMessenger' )->addMessage( 'I\'ve already been here!' );
    unset( $_SESSION['xyz-zyx'] );
}
$_SESSION['xyz-zyx'] = true;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Checked just now, but setting codes for the redirector doesn't change anything.

Comment: Do you use rewrite rules that perform a redirect? And after a redirect, the $_POST data should not be available anymore ...

Comment: Yes, I am using rewrite rules, but I am not relying on $_POST here, I am storing my data in a session object when I leave firstAction(), and it is available in secondAction(). You could see this setup as a very very simple wizard. The thing is, I could unset the session object after saving, but that will trigger an error the second time the controller code gets activated by the redirect. A possible way around this is checking for $_POST params, but then there would still be a second time the code is activated... The data wouldn't be saved twice and there won't be an error... But still..

Comment: If there is a redirect and you rely on session data, I don't think there is another way than to mark your data as processed to avoid saving the data twice. I don't think it is likely that gotoSimple() executes two redirects ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was caused by using Zend_DataGrid (BvBGrid). Rewrote the entire action and fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your server log or monitor your network and you will see that the browser is sending the same request twice--before the actual redirect.

I have seen many behaviors in browsers where they send a request twice. There are several reasons but also add-ons which fire a second request messing with your application. In one case it was something simple like a missing favicon.ico or a broken link to a image file. This all is fine and doesn't bother you until you begin working with session state or form submissions.

Once you know what is triggering the second request you should not only fix that but also add additional measures to prevent a second request from any browser.